# Django Rest Framework Pagination - Return last page by default

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-rest-framework

I am working on a chats app using django rest framework to return a list of messages.

These are my codes in api.py

```
class MessageList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Message.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MessageSerializer
    pagination_class = MessagePagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(MessageList, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(room__id=self.kwargs.get('pk')).order_by('id')
```

Using http://localhost:8000/chats/message-list/[room_pk]/?page=?, I was able to get the list of messages I wanted in different pages.

However, I would like the last page to be returned by default since I will also be implementing js infinite scrolling later on. In other words, by entering the url http://localhost:8000/chats/message-list/[room_pk]/, the last page objects will be return instead.

I am pretty new in django rest framework so I really appreciate any help given. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If just ordering is your concern then you should try `return queryset.filter(room__id=self.kwargs.get('pk')).order_by('-id')` instead of what you are already using.

Comment: @MuhammadFahadManzoor post that as an answer. Its probably correct.

Comment: I also think so but I would like to have a confirmation from @chronox before I post it as an answer.

Comment: @chronox in your function `get_queryset` you have the  `.order_by('...')` attribute. As the Name is suggesting it orders your QueySet. You can order for time or numbers or alphabetical etc. When you put a "-" infant of your order Keyword its the opposite. So Ordering for "-id" or "-time" should do the trick. You can only order for valid arguments. ID is always defined but you would have to define "time" by yourself to use it. If you have questions feel free to ask

Comment: Read the documentation on `Filtering` and `Pagination`. It will help what you want to acheive.

Comment: @MuhammadFahadManzoor ok, I think I get what you all meant. Thanks for the help

Comment: @chronox let me know if this solved your problem so I can post it as answer for you to accept/approve.

Comment: @MuhammadFahadManzoor yup it does. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to view the latest objects, then you may consider overriding the `ordering` attribute of the model.

```
class Message(models.Model):
    ....
    ....

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-id', )
```

By setting the `Meta` attribute `ordering`, you are explicitly setting all querysets of this model to return the latest created objects. This way you don't have to write unnecessary code for the same functionality.

PS: Don't forget `makemigrations` and `migrate`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired data/result by using following.

```
return queryset.filter(room__id=self.kwargs.get('pk')).order_by('-i‌​d')
```

Be at known that `-` with any field can change the sorting order, be it alphabetical (string) or numerical (int). Happy Python-ing to you!